# Apache http to https WITHOUT any adress?

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

a normal http to https rewrite could look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
# RewriteRule /.* https://example.com/ [R]
```

but this code specifies the site to **"example.com"**

Is there anyway to make a "**global**" rewrite, so regardless if anybody opens **example.com, broken.example.com**  or even **example.Lom**, (*as long as the DNS is pointing to the server*) so will it simply put a https on it?

for servers that have more than one domain name.

Would be great to be able to use the same code everywhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in any virtual host to redirect http to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

You can set it *globally* by setting the code in your default virtualhost (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` on debian) to redirect any http request on any domain to its https version:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```